# obtener la fecha con mas registro mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo un dilema, quiero obtener la fecha(día, mes y año) que mas registro ha tenido en mysql.

por ejemlo aqui el dia que mas registro ha tenido contando el ID es el día 02/12/2022, pero nose como podria realizar la consulta.

Alguien podría ayudarme por favor.

| ID | FECHA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/12/2022 |
| 2 | 01/12/2022 |
| 3 | 02/12/2022 |
| 4 | 02/12/2022 |
| 5 | 02/12/2022 |
| 6 | 03/12/2022 |

Esto es lo que tengo ahorita

```
SELECT t.fecha AS dia, COUNT(t.id) AS total 

FROM tickets t 

WHERE YEAR(t.fecha ) = '2022' 

AND t.is_active = 1 

GROUP BY dia
```

Y me lo devuelve asi

| dia | total |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-09 03:33:09 | 1 |
| 2022-10-09 14:41:30 | 1 |
| 2022-10-09 14:42:10 | 1 |
| 2022-10-09 15:05:56 | 1 |
| 2022-10-09 15:28:18 | 1 |
| 2022-10-10 17:09:21 | 1 |
| 2022-10-10 17:31:03 | 1 |
| 2022-10-10 17:42:32 | 1 |
| 2022-10-10 18:03:51 | 1 |
| 2022-10-11 22:57:42 | 1 |

Comment: Investiga sobre `GROUP BY`

Comment: Y también HAVING y LIMIT

Comment: Ya realice una consulta pero no me da el resultado que quiero

Comment: Es que estás haciendo `GROUP BY` sobre el día _y la hora_. Buscá la forma de "truncar" el valor de `t.fecha` para que solo te devuelva la fecha, sin la hora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con ésta consulta:

```
SELECT DATE(t.fecha) AS fecha, COUNT(t.id) AS total 
FROM tickets t 
WHERE YEAR(t.fecha) = '2022' 
AND t.is_active = 1 
GROUP BY DATE(t.fecha) 
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

En donde:

- Selecciono a `t.fecha` con el objeto `DATE()` para extraer solo el día, mes y año => `DATE(t.fecha)`.
- Agrupo por la fecha => `GROUP BY DATE(t.fecha)`.
- Ordeno por el total de manera descendente => `ORDER BY total DESC`.
- Y por último, obtengo solo el primer resultado (el mayor) => `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Funcionoooooooooooooooooo!! , muchas gracias !!!

Comment: Me parece que en vez de `LIMIT 1` también se puede usar `MAX`.

Comment: Y qué pasaría si la tabla tuvieras varias fechas con igual cantidad de registros,  me parece que en ese caso la respuesta que das no funciona, trata de analizar lo que te trato de decir, si existiesen varias fechas con la misma cantidad de registros la consulta es un poco más compleja

Comment: @Japv gracias por la sugerencia, solo di una respuesta que le serviría al OP en su caso (no tomé en cuenta que tendría muchos datos, claro que ahí sería distinto).